# Ubuntu 18.04 problem partitioning with GParted

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, gparted

I'm trying to partition my sda2. Right now I have:

sda1: fat32: efi

sda2: lvm2 pv: ubuntu-vg

But GParted says my sd2 has 0b unused space.
I used du -sh /*; but I have nothing that consumes all the spaces.

Anyone has an idea? Thx

Comment: Your LVM seems a likely candidate.

Comment: @user535733 yea, that may be the case